# How to use wake_up_interruptible

Tags: linux-kernel

I wonder how can I use wake_up_interruptible, if it returns void: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/wait.h#L161 (_wake_up function returns void). For example, down_interruptible function returns int: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/semaphore.c#L75 This allows to write such code, for example:

```
if ( down_interruptible(&dev->sem) )
    return -ERESTARTSYS;
// continue: down_interruptible succeeded
```

When I call wake_up_interruptible, and it is interrupted, how can I know this, if it returns void?

Comment: Well, the answer is that wake_up_interruptible cannot be interrupted, so there is no point to test return value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i suppose normal usage scenario would be, in one thread:

```
for (;;) {
   wait_event_interruptible(wait_queue, condition);
   /* Some processing */
}
```

and from some other thread:

```
if (something_happened)
   wake_up_interruptible(wait_queue);
```

which will result in one process from `wait_queue` which is in `TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE` state to be woken up and evalueate `condition`

see some more examples [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8144), a bit dated bit gives an idea